# Why does instance_methods(false) return ancestor methods?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

Running this code prints two lists of methods which are not the same size.  Why is that?

```
puts 'Subtracting ancestor methods:'
puts (Float.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods - Numeric.instance_methods).sort
puts
puts 'Requesting no ancestor methods:'
puts Float.instance_methods(false).sort
```

---

Subtracting ancestor methods:

```
*
**
+
-
/
finite?
infinite?
nan?
rationalize
to_f
to_i
to_r
```

Requesting no ancestor methods:

```
%
*
**
+
-
-@
/
<
<=
<=>
==
===
>
>=
abs
angle
arg
ceil
coerce
denominator
divmod
eql?
fdiv
finite?
floor
hash
infinite?
inspect
magnitude
modulo
nan?
numerator
phase
quo
rationalize
round
to_f
to_i
to_int
to_r
to_s
truncate
zero?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are not taking into account overridden methods.

```
class A
  def foo
    'A'
  end

  def bar
    'baz'
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo
    super + 'B'
  end
end

A.instance_methods(false) #=> [:foo, :bar]
B.instance_methods(false) #=> [:foo]
```

In this case both `A` and `B` have an instance method `:foo` at their own level, so they would both return `:foo` in their list of implemented instance methods.

I believe most of the methods that you believe have erroneously appeared in this list are similarly implemented in both `Float` and in `Numeric` with varying implementations.  Probably to handle the case where or both of the operands is a `Float`.